# How to properly write multiline text with LaTeX symbol in a frame and with background

Tags: plotting, legending, plot-themes, matex

I wanted to include a number of text-box with background color white inside a plot. The text inside the box will also have LaTex expressions as well as multiple lines.

**Is there any way to include multiline text (including LaTeX symbol) inside a plot?**

In addition  I  want to set frame and background color for the box.
I am currently using `Epilog` and `Prolog` to include such text.

```
  ListLinePlot[
  Table[{k, 
  PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}, {k, 0,50}], 
  Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Automatic,
  (**Option-1**)
  Epilog -> Text[Style[ToExpression["\\text{E}_{x} \\n text2", TeXForm, HoldForm],Bold],{30, 0.13}],
  (**Option-2**)
  Prolog -> {Inset[Framed[ "E_{x}\ntext2" , RoundingRadius -> 5,Background -> White], {45, 0.13}]}
  (**Option-3**)
(*Prolog -> {Inset[Framed[ MaTeX["E_{x}\\n text2" ] , RoundingRadius -> 5,Background ->White],{45,0.13}]}*)
   ]
```

`Option-1` fails writing `E_{x}` as well as breaking line.
`Option-2` fails writing `E_{x}` but breaks line.
`Option-3` is the one I wanted but it fails in breaking line.

Is there any way to achieve this.

Moreover I also wanted to ask, what should one do if one has to include say more that two text boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that I can use `Grid` which solves all the problem.

```
  ListLinePlot[
  Table[{k, 
  PDF[BinomialDistribution[50, p], k]}, {p, {0.3, 0.5, 0.8}}, {k, 0,50}], 
  Filling -> Axis, 
  FillingStyle -> Automatic,

  (**Option-3**)
  Prolog -> {Inset[Framed[Grid[{ {MaTeX["E_{x}"]}, {MaTeX["text2"]} }] , 
RoundingRadius -> 5, Background -> White], {45, 0.13}]}
   ]
```